# Before I move my arm the brain sends signals - what causes the brain to send signals?

Tags: brain, muscles, central-nervous-system

1. Please tell me what causes the brain to send signals, how does the brain send signals?
2. can you tell me what happens between the point when you make an intention to pick up a glass of water, and before the brains sends signals to the body which excites the muscles.

So what happens at the moment when you make the intention to pick up a glass of water but before the brains sends signals after you reach to pick up a glass of water.

Comment: subquestion one seems too broad, but the remainder is interesting.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Action potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_potential) - I haven't read through the entire Wikipedia article so I can't vouch for its accuracy (not that my neurophysiology is good enough to critique it), but it's probably a good start.
2. Broadly speaking: the brain contains different regions that are each responsible for fairly specific tasks. In the case of picking up a glass of water we can, at a high level, describe the mechanism behind thirst. Your blood contains electrolytes in water; you can consider the electrolytes as being like cordial (reduce the water and you have a higher [concentration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_osmolality) of cordial / electrolytes). A sensing mechanism (beyond the scope of this answer) will trigger action potentials between the relevant areas of the brain (motor, memory, etc.) to result in the final movement.

Comment: satisfying answer. nice answer to the question. good attempt because this question I think is not asked before I think.

Comment: i think question is bizzare, so there is no need to judge any answers posted

Comment: question isn't bizarre, question is good, god wants mankind to learn more about his creation, you just don't know, you are not knowledgeable enough to know what questions are good or not. just be quiet

Answer (score 1):

1) There is always a persistent sodium current which is slowly inactivating in comparison with the fast transient sodium current that occurs when a neuron is depolarized. The effects of this persistent sodium current brings the resting membrane potential near the threshold. Furthermore, neurons do indeed fire and reach depolarization state due to these fluctuations in membrane potential, but those action potentials will not always cause a depolarization of the post-synaptic neurons, since those neurons have inputs of convergence from inhibitory neurons that produce inhibitory post-synaptic potentials. There is no moment or situations where all of your neurons are quiet.
Further information about persistent sodium current can be read in French et al.,1990., "A Voltage-dependent Persistent Sodium Current in Mammalian Hippocampal Neurons"., J. Gen. Physiol., Vol 95;1139-1157 http://jgp.rupress.org/content/95/6/1139.full.pdf

2) The brain center which is thought to play an important role, not only in decision making, but also in behavioral control of the decision making dependent on the reward and outcome, is the prefrontal cortex. Except for its associative learning capabilities prefrontal cortex is thought to have neuronal connections with many part of other brain structures and it must first gather information and integrate the information before deciding what to do. In your question the reward is the glass of water, the emotional response you would get to drink that cold water would aid to the decision making, and the motoric movement is initiated by the subsequent firing of neurons when you see the glass of water and when you recall/remember the feeling to drink it. Prefrontal cortex is therefore activated and can thereafter send action potentials to motor cortex and then to your peripheral nervous system and muscles, so you can pick up the glass of water.

More about this here: http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0959438800001926/1-s2.0-S0959438800001926-main.pdf?_tid=83268f2a-eed1-11e4-ae1f-00000aab0f6c&acdnat=1430354614_ddc06d6aeae4543af28ebe02e29486cc